# Setting CMAKE_SYSROOT by generator expression

Tags: cmake

In our project we are setting [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) depending on the selected configuration. It is so because configuration expresses (amongst others) target platform (cross-compilation - but not only, also slight behavior differences).

We would like to express this with [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to be friendly towards multi-configuration IDEs.

However, we haven't found a way to do so. First, you will notice that [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) doesn't even mention such a possibility. We still tried to set it to something like this (not exact value - just a sample!):

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT $<IF:$<CONFIG:hw1>,path1,path2>)
```

hoping that the value is used in a context where [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) are supported. But apparently, it is not. Instead, it seems that the verbatim value is provided in `--sysroot` argument (`--sysroot="\$<IF:\$<CONFIG:hw1>,path1,path2>"`). Adding quotes around the value doesn't change anything.

What other options do we have?

---

Let me also add a note on the [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html#variable:CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE) which is mentioned in the documentation of [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html).

I don't see the [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html#variable:CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE) being set to anything after `grep`-ing through files generated by `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=hw1 ../` and our own sources.

Apparently, the file where we set the [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) is not pointed to by [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html#variable:CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE). Yet, still, the `--sysroot` argument is being set to the expected value. (Only not by [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)!) So, it does work *somehow*.

---

I expect we will have the same issue with other variables as well:

- [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html),
- [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html),
- [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html),
- [`CMAKE_C_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html)

the last two depend on the [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) anyway (in our case).

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to pass different `--sysroot` flags to the linker on a multi-configuration generator you'll just have to pass it via `target_link_options` using a generator expression.  But then you might have to update `rpath` items yourself, but I'm not sure about that.

Variables are not used at build time and the documentation for generator expressions state:
`Generator expressions are allowed in the context of many target properties...`

I didn't see anything in the `set` command that prevents `CMAKE_SYSROOT` being set outside a tool-chain file.  I'm guessing that the phrase `This variable may only be set in a toolchain file` should be `This variable is normally used in a toolchain file`.

It almost seems like that you are trying to use build type as a switch between two different tool chains.  If that is the case then I don't see how that could work correctly with a multi-configuration generator.  Most of everything you want to set is determined and used at configuration time not build time.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that essentially I want to switch between different toolchains. But why wouldn't that work? From my POV it seems to be just a set of arguments in a call to a compiler. From my POV it doesn't differ from changing other compiler flags. So, where is the difficulty?

Comment: I expected I could manually add the `--sysroot`. But firstly I'm not sure what else mygiht relay on the variable and I would have to take care of it as well. And secondly, what about the other variables I mentioned that don't seem to correspond well to compiler/linker arguments?

Comment: @AdamBadura `CMAKE_<lang>_COMPILER` isn't a compiler flag.  It is the compiler.  Once `CMake` see the `project` command it runs tests to see which compiler family you are using, what default compiler options to use, that sort of thing. This happens when CMake configures and generates the build files. Once determined the compiler can't be changed when using the build tool, e.g. `make`.  The difficulty is that the functionality you are asking for is simply not implemented.